# Event ionic return to a view

Tags: android, ionic-framework

in my application I am evaluating whether this or not active in GPS in the device. If it is not, give the option to activate it and return to the view where the user was, however Android, then turn and hit the back of the same phone button, I can not refresh the view, not working events `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter')` I've used each time you enter a view. There is some method to identify whether it was an active view, I quit and returned to be?

Comment: You are not quiting  your view if you perform something like that but you put it "in stand by" to go to Android tools.
Therefore, the event ionicView shall not be launched.
By the way, what cordova plugin do you use to check GPS status activation & redirection ?

Comment: @aorfevre Hi, thanks for responding. You do not know how I can do what I want? since you say that any kind of ionicView is generated when the user command to configure your GPS. Incidentally, the plugin I use is diagnostic Cordova, several plugins that can be verified.

Comment: You are calling a function for your Cordova plugin. Then use the callback of that function

Comment: I do not know that, if he could give me some help I would appreciate, leave it in response. @aorfevre